# How can I get the current month as String?

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate, nscalendar

I need to get may as a current month, but I could not do. How can I achieve this?

```
   let date = NSDate()
   let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
   let components = calendar.components([.Day , .Month , .Year], fromDate: date)
   
   let year =  components.year
   let month = components.month
   let day = components.day
```

I have done this but does not worked.

Comment: Do you want the ordinal number as string, the month name (in which language) or something else? And consider to update to Swift 3. That's the future.

Comment: @vadian 3 is already past. We are at 3.1

Comment: @LeoDabus Of course I mean Swift 3 in terms of `≥` like a major upgrade.

Comment: @vadian I am just showing how important is for him to upgrade as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
let now = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLLL"
let nameOfMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
```

Comment: The correct format for stand alone month is LLLL http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Comment: Is it possible to set the language of the returned month? I tried using locale but it doesn't work. I want to get the current language that is set on iPhone

Comment: @codddeer123 The `DateFormatter` uses the device's locale by default. You can override it by setting a different locale of course: `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es")`

Comment: If you are displaying something more than just the month, for example month and day, this might be prone to issues. Better to use `.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` to account for possible localization format order differences.

Answer (score 48):

If you are using **Swift 3.0** then extensions and **Date** class are great way to go.

try below code

```
extension Date {
    var month: String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }    
}
```

Get work with it like below:

```
 let date = Date()
 let monthString = date.month
```

Comment: i am using swift 2

Comment: just get on Swift 3.0 if you can bro. bcz its a lot happening on latest **swift**

Comment: Swift 4.0 Solution: DateFormatter().monthSymbols[currentMonth - 1]

Comment: I would change it to `static var month: String { .... }` so it can be accessed without having to create an instance.

Answer (score 16):

### Swift 3.0 and higher

You use DateFormatter() see below for this used in an extension to Date.

Add this anywhere in your project in global scope.

```
extension Date {
    func monthName() -> String {
            let df = DateFormatter()
            df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMM")
            return df.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Then you can use this anywhere in your code.

```
let date = Date()
date.monthName() // Returns current month e.g. "May"
```

Comment: should i use NSdate date is undeclared ....swift 2